# VBA - From Excel, pull ppt template (potx) and use customlayout from the template?

Tags: excel, vba, layout, powerpoint

I've been wrestling with using Excel to create PowerPoint slide using a .potx file as the powerpoint template.

The problem I have is that I am not able to figure out how to duplicate the slidemaster so I can use custom layouts.

I want a new presentation created that uses the layouts defined in the .potx file?

I'm brand new to VBA so my code is a little rough on the edges.

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()
'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Range Into a New PowerPoint Presentation
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim mytextbox As Object
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Dim trueranges As New Collection 'Store the ranges to be used in master excel file
Dim start_counting_from_this_row_number As Integer 'starting value of rows to search for TRUE/FALSE
Dim worksheetnames As New Collection 'collect all worksheet names if TRUE
Dim rg As Range
Const PXLtoINCH As Single = 72# 'PP uses pixels not inches, this is the conversion factor
Dim SQPOSITION As Double
Dim SQHeight As Double
Dim range_shape As New WSOrgDisplayAttributes
Dim all_data As New Collection

'*******************************************************************************************************************

'Check to see if Master Data Sheet Spreadsheet is in same directory and if so, open it.
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileNameOnly As String

FileNameOnly = "WS Asset Availability Master Data Spreadsheet.xlsx"
FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileNameOnly

If IsFile(FilePath) = True Then 'ENDIF is near the end of the SUB
    If CheckFileIsOpen(FileNameOnly) = False Then
        Workbooks.Open (FileName)
        MsgBox ("A small time Delay...(This ensures file is open and ready for use")
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")) 'this allows time to open before other parts of macro run
    End If


'*******************************************************************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************************************************
    'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
      On Error Resume Next

        'Is PowerPoint already opened?
          Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")

        'Clear the error between errors
          Err.Clear

        'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
          If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")

        'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
          If Err.Number = 429 Then
            MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
            Exit Sub
          End If

      On Error GoTo 0

    'Optimize Code
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Create a New Presentation
      Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
      myPresentation.ApplyTemplate (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "SRR Template.potx")


      'myPresentation.ApplyTemplate (FilePath & "\" & "SRR Template.potx")
    '*******************************************************************************************************************
    '*******************************************************************************************************************

    'Initialize variables
    start_counting_from_this_row_number = 3 'Find row where first TRUE/FALSE is under column "D"
    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SRR Helper").Range("D1").CurrentRegion 'count the max rows

    SQPOSITION = 6 'inches
    SQHeight = 0.18 'inches

    '*******************************************************************************************************************
    '*******************************************************************************************************************

    'Push all TRUE's to collections
    'ADD HEADER INFO LATER
    For x = start_counting_from_this_row_number To rg.Rows.Count
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SRR Helper").Range("D" & x).Value = True Then
            Set range_shape = Nothing
            range_shape.let_range_check = True
            range_shape.let_shape_range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SRR Helper").Range("C" & x).Value
            range_shape.let_sheet_name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SRR Helper").Range("E" & x).Value

            all_data.Add range_shape
        End If
    Next x


'*******************************************************************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************************************************

    'Iterate through collections to push Master File to PP presenation
    Dim iterator As New WSOrgDisplayAttributes
    Dim iterator2 As New WSOrgDisplayAttributes

    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 1) 'Always create at least one slide    myPresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts (GetLayoutIndexFromName("SRRLayout", myPresentation.Designs(1)))

    myPresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen 'Set slide orientation and size

    Dim sheet_counter As Integer
    sheet_counter = 1
    Dim updateslide As Boolean
    Dim temp As Double
    temp = (SQPOSITION) * PXLtoINCH

    For i = 1 To all_data.Count
        'Set Worksheet
        Set iterator = all_data(i)
        Set iterator2 = Nothing

        If all_data.Count = 1 Then
            updateslide = False 'only one sheet so no need for new slide, they are equal
        Else
            If i = all_data.Count Then ' last element can't be compared with the next, but can be compared to previous
                Set iterator2 = all_data(i - 1)

                If iterator2.get_sheet_name = iterator.get_sheet_name Then
                    updateslide = False
                Else
                    updateslide = True
                    sheet_counter = sheet_counter + 1
                End If
            Else
                Set iterator2 = all_data(i + 1)
                If iterator2.get_sheet_name = iterator.get_sheet_name Then
                    updateslide = False
                Else
                    updateslide = True
                    sheet_counter = sheet_counter + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If


        Set Ws = Workbooks("WS Asset Availability Master Data Spreadsheet.xlsx").Sheets(iterator.get_sheet_name)

        'Copy Range from Excel
        Set rg = Ws.Range(iterator.get_shape_range)

        'Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:1"))
        'Copy Excel Range
        rg.Copy

        'Paste to PowerPoint and position

        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count) 'Control the latest shape to be pasted

        'Set position:
        myShape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        myShape.Height = 0.62 * PXLtoINCH
        myShape.Width = 9.74 * PXLtoINCH
        myShape.Left = 0.14 * PXLtoINCH
        myShape.Top = temp
        temp = myShape.Top + myShape.Height

        If updateslide = True Then
            temp = (SQPOSITION) * PXLtoINCH ' reset temp back to starting position.
        End If


        'Add a slide to the Presentation - only if new sheetname
        If updateslide = True Then
            Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(sheet_counter, 2) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
            updateslide = False
            temp = (SQPOSITION) * PXLtoINCH
        End If
    Next i

'*******************************************************************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************************************************

    'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
      PowerPointApp.Visible = True
      PowerPointApp.Activate

    'Clear The Clipboard
      Application.CutCopyMode = False

'*******************************************************************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************************************************

Else
    MsgBox ("File Does not Exist in local directory - WS Asset Availability Master Data Spreadsheet.xlsx")
End If

End Sub



Function IsFile(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
'Returns TRUE if the provided name points to an existing file.
'Returns FALSE if not existing, or if it's a folder
    On Error Resume Next
    IsFile = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
End Function



Function CheckFileIsOpen(chkSumfile As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    CheckFileIsOpen = (Workbooks(chkSumfile).Name = chkSumfile)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function




Function GetLayoutIndexFromName(sLayoutName As String, oDes As Design) As Long

    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To oDes.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Count

        If oDes.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(x).Name = sLayoutName Then

            GetLayoutIndexFromName = x

            Exit Function

        End If

    Next

End Function
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?  Which part of the code isn't working as expected?  It's not clear.  By the way, for future reference, PPT uses points, not pixels, as dimensions. That won't matter to your code though.  Also, why do you need to duplicate the slide master?

Comment: I've since changed the method I am using to create the presentation. I now open the template power point slide show and edit that. Then I am saving that copy as something else so I don't destroy the original template when I make changes to it. The problem I am having now is that I want to create an exact copy of slide 1 from the template for later use. However, I end up editing slide 1 (after making a copy) and then all the copies end up with the changes as well. This is because I am making a copy to the reference instaed of byval. Is there a way to copy a slide object by value?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're doing or why you're seeing this; can you post the updated code?